# How to calculate the time needed for the UVC to be turned on and disinfect a specific space/location?

Tags: uv

I have 3x60W UVC tube with a 254 nm wavelength. I want to know until **up to what meter the range will cover and disinfect the area and how to calculate the time needed for these 3 tubes to be turned on and totally disinfect the entire whole area**.

Comment: This question is not about electronics.

Comment: @StarCat Not well specified, but it's about as much about electronics as many questions which talk about and electronic or electrical device that  provides a service / application / capability. LED, bluetooth module, buck converter, ... . Yes? (No? :-) )

Comment: You need to provide MUCH more information to make your question able to be answered well Q1 Is this an assignment / homework? Q2 Links to all hardware - brand and model of tubes? Q3 What measure are you using for "totally disinfect? Where did you get it? / Why have you not got it? Links, references? Q5 What are you disinfecting? Disinfection requires a time intensity dose. Is your target moving or stationary? Does time matter? Q6 Other ....? || This question needs to be improved along the above lines or it will be closed as unanswerable.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about electronics.

Comment: You guys never heard the term optoelectronics? Where do you think this is taught? In literature curricula?

Comment: In addition to output power per area of your light, it also depends on what the surface is.  254nm will be relatively effective on smooth metal surfaces and especially transparent fluids like water, but will not be able to sterilize a porous surface at all.

Answer (score 1):

Dose Requirements are usually given in uJ/cm2, mJ/cm2, uW/cm2 or mW/cm2 and are not in power per covering radius and exposed time. So, it is the flow that must be taken into consideration for air treatment and you must consider recycled airflow treated by UV or treating air flowing inside air ducts like HVAC elements.

As vague measure it is noted in [this reference](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267198093_Guidelines_for_the_Utilisation_of_Ultraviolet_Germicidal_Irradiation_UVGI_Technology_in_Controlling_Transmission_of_Tuberculosis_in_Health_Care_Facilities_in_South_Africa) that the ideal UV-C intensity for effective disinfection must be greater than 10uW/cm2. But it depends also on the type of virus or bacteria you are fighting.

In all cases you must also consider the efficiency of the UV tubes.